# Using Command Line to parse arguments

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

I am trying to use [CommandLine](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline) to enable parsing parameters with my console application. I don't think I am using it correctly. I am trying to learn how to create different options, like -s for Symbol, and -d for Date. Here is my attempt:

```
public interface ICommandLineOption
    {
        string WhichOption { get; }
    }

[Verb("symbol", HelpText = "Symbol to test")]
public class SymbolCommand : ICommandLineOption
{
    public string WhichOption { get { return "Symbol"; } private set { } }

    [Option('s', "symbol", Required = true, HelpText = "Symbol To run backtest")]
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    
}

[Verb("begin", HelpText = "Start date of test")]
public class BeginDateCommand : ICommandLineOption
{
    public string WhichOption { get { return "BeginDate"; } private set { } }

    [Option('d', "date", Required = true, HelpText = "Date to begin run of backtest")]
    public System.DateTime BeginDate { get; set; }
    
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Parser.Default.ParseArguments<ICommandLineOption>(args).WithParsed<ICommandLineOption>(o =>
    {
        switch (o.WhichOption)
        {
            case "Symbol":
                {
                    var comm = o as SymbolCommand;
                    Console.WriteLine(comm.Symbol);
                    break;
                }
            case "BeginDate":
                {
                    var comm = o as BeginDateCommand;
                    Console.WriteLine(comm.BeginDate);
                    break;
                }
            default:
                break;
        }
    });
}
```

But this doesn't work:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in CommandLine.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in CommandLine.dll
Type ICommandLineOption appears to be immutable, but no constructor found to accept values
```

Comment: Based on the documentation, you don't really need an interface. Use multiple annotated methods of one class

Comment: You need to explain what *doesn't work* means. What is the desired behavior? What is the actual behavior?

Comment: Are the parameters not already parsed, atl least by spaces?

Comment: I modified the OP to show the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily achieved with the Nuget library [CommandLineParser](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
       Parser.Default.ParseArguments<CommandLineOptions>(args)
       .WithParsed<CommandLineOptions>(o =>
       {
                Console.WriteLine(o.Symbol);
                Console.WriteLine(o.Date);
       });
     ...
}

public class CommandLineOptions
{
    [Option('s', "symbol", Required = true, HelpText = "Symbol To run backtest")]
    public string Symbol { get; set; }

    [Option('d', "date", Required = true)]
    public string Date { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Please add more context to this, what libraries are used, etc..